# How can I fetch a path from a preference page and use it in a process started by a button?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have made a preference page whose program code is --

```
public class SAML
    extends FieldEditorPreferencePage
    implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    public SAML() {
        super(GRID);
        setPreferenceStore(RmpPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
        setDescription("Browse Appropriate files");
    }

    public FileFieldEditor f;
    public FileFieldEditor f1;
    public void createFieldEditors() {
        f = new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH, 
                "&Prism.bat File:", getFieldEditorParent());
        addField(f);

        f1 = new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH1, 
                "&NuSMV Application File:", getFieldEditorParent());
        addField(f1);
    }
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
    }
}
```

In this preference page, there are two **FileFieldEditor** which is use to select "prism.bat" and "NuSMV.exe" file.

I have accessed path in my another button programming whose code is ---

```
try {           
    IPreferenceStore store = plugin.getPreferenceStore();

    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH));
    pb.directory(new File(store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH)));
    Process p=pb.start();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String in;
    while((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(in);
    }

    int exitVal=p.waitFor();            

   if(exitVal==0)
   {
        out.println("Printing on console");
   }
   else
       out.println("Process failed");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    out.println(e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Whenever I am clicking the button after selecting Prism.bat file from preference page, it says that file not found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code and see what this computes to
store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH));
    pb.directory(new File(store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH))

excute it from the command line and see what is missing. My guess is that there is a space character in your path which is breaking it. Quotify the path may fix it. But see the string and decide accordingly.

Comment: -thanks for the response.Error is - 

**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory ""): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**

I am new to Eclipse. Please help me. Moreover, Can you let me know, how to save the state of the Preference Page, Suppose if i select **"Prism.bat"** and **NuSMV.exe"** file first time from FileFieldEditor then next time its should save the state of my selected file. Currently, it is saving only one i.e either the path of **PRISM.BAT** or **NuSMV.exe** even if i have selected different file from FileFieldEditor.

Comment: I mean do something like this 
 String command = store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH));
    pb.directory(new File(store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH));
 System.out.println(command); // see this output and run it on command prompt. This shall tell you what are you missing
 ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command);

Comment: I tried this method. And the output is nothing.. Simply blank....
Which means that 
**String command = store.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH);**

is not getting the path from preference page!
So what next is to be checked.

Comment: This is because you are not probably writing to Preferences before reading it. You should go thru some related tutorials first and get the understanding of it. This should serve you as starting point http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm